# Calling a batch file from a windows service

Tags: c, windows, service

I have a service that needs to call a batch when a new file is copied to a directory. I tried using `CreateProcess`, `ShellExecute`, `ShellExecuteEx` and even `system`. I tried calling the batch directly, then calling `cmd.exe` and passing `/c batchfile` as parameter... Nothing.
I set the service to run as administrator. I tried with other users. Nothing.

This is a Windows 2008 server.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: What does this bat file do? How does it fail?

Comment: it just moves files around and adds a line to a text file. It doesn't fail. it just doesn't run, at all.

Comment: Which files does it move? Are they in any special location, e.g. system folders, user profile folders etc.

Comment: No, nothing special. just a file from directory Dir1 to Dir2. If you run the batch file manually it works. If you run the batch file from the service it doesn't

Comment: Local files, or files on the network? Drive mappings?

Comment: it's all local. NOTHING WEIRD HERE, IT JUST DOESNT RUN IT.

Comment: OK, I won't try to help anymore if you shout at me.

Comment: @Mr Aleph Good to see you got a solution. It was very obvious what the problem was once Kevin posted code. Too bad you didn't post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), as shown in the (grossly simplified) example below, is a valid way to execute a batch file from a service.

```
STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
si.cb = sizeof(si);

if( !CreateProcessA( NULL,
                     "C:\\test.bat",
                     NULL,
                     NULL,
                     FALSE,
                     0,
                     NULL,
                     NULL,
                     &si,
                     &pi
                   ) )
{
    char msg[100];
    sprintf( msg, "CreateProcess() failed: %d", GetLastError() );
    OutputDebugStringA( msg );
}
```

Logging is key. If the batch file isn't being executed, CreateProcess() will tell you why.

You mention that the batch file is to be executed "when a new file is copied to a directory." Have you verified that the detection code is working properly? Is the code attempting to execute the batch file actually reached?

More context would definitely be helpful. Please post the relevant portions of the batch file and service code.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what my code looks like. I placed debugging calls to a log file and 1) CreateProcess returns success, 2) the batch file gets reached and 3) the detection of the new file in the directory works. The same code ran from a command line application works 100%. Not from a service.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using full, absolute paths in your call to `CreateProcess` since the working directory when the service is running might not be what you think it is (I've made this mistake more times than I'd like to admit).

See if the behavior changes if you replace the batch file with something simple like:

```
@echo TESTING >C:\batch_debug.txt
```

That should give a better picture of whether the batch file isn't being executed at all or if there's something in the batch file that is causing a problem.

What kind of a return value are you getting from `CreateProcess`?  If it fails, does `GetLastError` give you any useful information?

**UPDATE:**
I think the issue here is that [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is limited to executables.  You can launch a batch file but you have to pass it as a parameter to `cmd.exe`.  You also have to list the parameters separately from the executable name.  For example, if the command `cmd.exe /c C:\my_batch.bat` would normally run your batch file in a new command interpreter instance, the following `CreateProcess` call should do the same thing:

```
CreateProcess("cmd.exe", "/c C:\\my_batch.bat", ...);
```

Comment: Thanks. CreateProcess returns success and it doesn't matter what I write in the batch file, it doesn't get executed. I wrote the echo, I wrote dir, and pretty much all kind of tests. Nothng.

Comment: Can your same code launch some other program that isn't your batch file?  For example, what happens when you substitute the path to your batchfile with the path to `notepad.exe`?

Comment: no problem. running any .exe is fine. running a batch file is not. I already tried all the possible combinations and I already tried running exe's, running with admin privileges, running with system privileges, turning UAC on and off, etc, etc, etc. I am asking here because I exhausted every possibility and I thought people would know **how** to execute a batch file from a service.

Comment: The problem here just dawned on me (it's been a while since I've done this).  I'll edit it into my answer momentarily.

Comment: Thanks. If you see my question you can see that I already tried that and still doesn't work. I guess there is no answer

Comment: If code like I mentioned above doesn't work, then something is definitely wrong.  That code is exactly what is mentioned in Microsoft's documentation for CreateProcess (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: microsoft documentation is known for having code that doesn't work. I don't trust it and this is an example of it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to run->services.msc->right click on the service ->properties->
logon->check enable     service to interact with desktop-make it enable
```