# How to call a batch file from a windows service?

Tags: java, batch-file, windows-services

we have a java application, which is running as windows service. Actually we need to call a batch file to start windows 'calculator' application. But we can't. If we start java application not as a windows service, it is working fine. I have read a post about the same on  [Calling a batch file from a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327222/calling-a-batch-file-from-a-windows-service#comment6052525_5329479) and done the below configuration.

"first install the service with giving appropriate path to the batch file or exe file then go to run->services.msc->right click on the service ->properties->logon->check enable service to interact with desktop-make it enable "

After that we got a partial success, as it first prompts a permission window as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that instead of opening a batch file, you just open the calc.exe file instead?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\windows\\System32\\calc.exe", null, new File("c:\\windows\\System32\\calc.exe"));
```

EDIT: If you still want to run it as a batch file, use this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start nameOfTheBatchFile.bat");
```

Please note that the second variable in the exec method is to set up the directory that you want to be calling the program from.

Comment: Why calling `cmd` to call `start` ro call batch? Why not `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nameOfTheBatchFile.bat");`?

Comment: Because a batch file is not an executable, it runs under cmd

Comment: Ok, but why not just `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c nameOfTheBatchFile.bat");` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start nameOfTheBatchFile.bat");`? Why 3 processes?

Comment: If you read my answer already said about calling cmd... Reason behind calling start is that is creates a new process and lets cmd close otherwise cmd will stay open until you close the batch file which won't end until you close the calc

Comment: If read my question I could understand your answer... Please read before answering :) Really: you can't launch batch because is not executable - agree! But you can launch it with just one `cmd` call or with just a `start` call. Why would you need both?

Comment: Ok... `start` is also an internal `cmd` command, so can't also be launched. But `cmd /c` should terminate after batch: "/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates"

Comment: As I said if you don't call start it would leave the cmd black screen open until you close the calc. Start will avoid that :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34603/discussion-between-ls-dev-and-jose-sutilo)